# Azure Release Pipeline to deploy to AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-ec2, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm a leaner of Azure DevOps.
I Have successfully Build an angular application & deployed to AWS S3 bucket.
[image]

I was about to transfer the same Publish Pipeline Artifact files to AWS EC2.

I was given by,
Remote Computer: ec2-**-**-**-**.compute-1.amazonaws.com,
with UserName and Password

When i use SSH,
[image]

Above gives me below error:
[image]

Can you please help an example to transfer the Publish Pipeline Artifact files to AWS EC2.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is the remote machine public on Internet?

Answer (score 0):

You may check the following items:

1. Check whether the remote machine can be accessed in internet.
2. Try to check the SSH service connection to see whether you input correct information.
3. Set variable `system.debug` to `true` and clink the error step to check the detailed log.
4. Instead of using ssh copy, you may consider deploying an build agent on remote machine.

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?